# In kerr's black hole solution can the Bekenstein-Hawking entropy be descrete?

Tags: angular-momentum, hawking-radiation, black-hole-thermodynamics

In kerr's solution we have: 
$S_{BH}=\frac{k_{\beta}c^{3}A}{4G\hbar}$ where A is the area of the horizon 
and equal to $A=8\pi G^2 m(m+\sqrt{m^2 - a^2})$ where $a=\frac{J}{mc}$ and J is the angular momentum. If we set $G=\hbar=k_{\beta}=c=1$ then we have 
$A=8\pi m(m+\sqrt{m^2 - \frac{J^2}{m^2}})$ and $S_{BH}=2\pi m(m+\sqrt{m^2 - \frac{J^2}{m^2}})$. In this point I make the assumption that angular momentum has discrete eigenvalues in other words J is an operator that: $J^2 |\psi> = n(n+1)|\psi>$ and the entropy becomes $\hat S_{BH}|\psi>=2\pi m(m+\sqrt{m^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{m^2}})|\psi>$. Can I do that?